# Drupal: Hide and Show cck fields in nodes

Tags: drupal

It is possiblle to hide cck fields and show other cck field when you choose a combobox opcion in a node?

For example: combobox opcions: 1 field, 2 fields

If I select 1 field, my form has a text field
If I select 2 fields, my form has a text area and a imagefield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the [Conditional Fields module](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields).  After installing the module, you can use it as such:

1. In your content type, add a select box and in allowed values area add "1 field" and "2 fields"
2. Create a text field, you should see a fieldset titled "Conditional fields settings", open that and choose "1 field"
3. Do a similar process to create a textarea and imagefield but choose "2 fields" in the conditional fields settings.

Now when creating a content type, when changing the value of the select box will show different fields on the form.

More information:
[Example Screenshots](http://www.scritturacollettiva.org/conditional-fields-screenshots)
[Documentation for Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/node/475488)

Comment: Awesome!!! Conditional Fields is the module that i was looking for. Thank you very much laxman13.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Display Suite module. The easy way to do this is create a build mode for each view and enable the "switch build modes on node page" option - then you can override the text values of the build mode selector.